# Apache vhost config

Tags: apache-2.4, virtualhost

Hi i've tried to configure a vhost on my server but it's not working.

when trying to access it goes default...

this is my basic config.

On my server:

/var/www/html/blentico.com/public_html/index.php (and Wordpress packages)

/etc/apache2/sites-available/blentico.com.conf

this is the content of blentico.com.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerAdmin admin@blentico.com
ServerName blentico.com
Serveralias www.blentico.com
DocumentRoot /var/www/html/blentico.com/public_html
ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

then i run the command:

a2ensite blentico.com.conf

all my files/directories inside /var/www have user/group root and 755 permission

ok, so, i suppose that this is OK according to all the docs i've read but when i try to access to www.blentico.com it goes directly to my index.php file located in /var/www/html/index.php and no to /var/www/html/blentico.com/public_html as i've indicated on my blentico.com.conf file.

hope you can help me.

Comment: Post your solution as an answer, please, not as an edit to your question.

Answer (score 0):

At the very least you need to wrap your configuration with `<VirtualHost></VirtualHost>` tags. Otherwise I imagine it'll just get merged into the default configuration. See https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/vhosts/ for more information on setting up vhosts.

Comment: Sorry about that , forgot to copy that. the file already had < VirtualHost * : 80>
Now I edit the text

Answer (score 0):

Done!

My default config (**000-default.conf**) were active and with no ServerName so always ended in this DocumentRoot (DocumentRoot of 000-default.conf file), right? i think yes cos when i deactivate this config with **a2dissite 000-default** and restart apache my config start working.
i've also made some modifications to my config file although that doesn't make any difference to my first problem. Anyway i show it below

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

    ServerAdmin admin@blentico.com
    ServerName blentico.com
    Serveralias www.blentico.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/blentico.com/public_html

    ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/blentico.com-error.log
    CustomLog /var/log/apache2/blentico.com-access.log combined

    <Directory /var/www/html/blentico.com/public_html>
            Order allow,deny
            allow from all
    </Directory>
```